# is LGM without factor variance just comparing means?

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, growth-model

Let’s say a simple latent growth model with just two time points, constrained the variance of these two time points to be zero. Are the latent intercept and latent slope then merely using the mean scores of these two time points? (Never minding the fact that a LGM with just two time points isn’t very practical).

Thanks!

Comment: How do you define a LGM mathematically?

Comment: As far as I understand, a LGM is a two level confirmatory factor analysis. Where the indicators measure the time points, and the time points measure the latent intercept and latent slope. The knowns of a CFA are given by the variance-covariance structure and the means structure. I think that by constraining the variances to be zero, the variance-covariance structure is absent and only the means structure is available? Is this correct?

Comment: I'm not sure. If you type everything up in $\LaTeX$, more people will be able to answer (perhaps there are some who might have the requisite skills, but don't have familiarity with the specifics)

Comment: Why would you constrain the variance to be zero? If you don't, then you are comparing the means. (I guess you could shift the variance to the measured variables.)

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm referring to a multiple indicator LGM (i.e. second order SEM). Multiple indicators are measured at two time points.

Comment: I'm a little confused. A model specification in the form of syntax or (probably better) a path diagram would help me.